# React selector js question: How can I convert an array's item into object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, reselect

Page link: https://nexus20201007.herokuapp.com/shop
https://nexus20201007.herokuapp.com/shop/hats
so here, what I am trying to accomplish is, if this function finds the object, I am able to map it and show it in a specific address.
Her is the shop.selector file:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const selectShop = state => state.shop;

export const selectCollections = createSelector(
  [selectShop],
  shop => shop.collections
);

export const selectCollectionsForPreview = createSelector(
  [selectCollections],
  collections => Object.keys(collections).map(key => collections[key])
);

export const selectCollection = collectionUrlParam =>
  createSelector(
    [selectCollections],
    collections => collections[collectionUrlParam]
  );
```

Here is the data file:

```
    const SHOP_DATA = {
  hats: {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Hats',
    routeName: 'hats',
    items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Brown Brim',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/ZYW3VTp/brown-brim.png',
        price: 25,
        linkUrl: 'hats/1'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Blue Beanie',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/ypkgK0X/blue-beanie.png',
        price: 18,
        linkUrl: 'hats/2'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Brown Cowboy',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/QdJwgmp/brown-cowboy.png',
        price: 35,
        linkUrl: 'hats/3'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Grey Brim',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/RjBLWxB/grey-brim.png',
        price: 25,
        linkUrl: 'hats/4'
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Green Beanie',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/YTjW3vF/green-beanie.png',
        price: 18,
        linkUrl: 'hats/5'
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        name: 'Palm Tree Cap',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/rKBDvJX/palm-tree-cap.png',
        price: 14,
        linkUrl: 'hats/6'
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        name: 'Red Beanie',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/bLB646Z/red-beanie.png',
        price: 18,
        linkUrl: 'hats/7'
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        name: 'Wolf Cap',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/1f2nWMM/wolf-cap.png',
        price: 14,
        linkUrl: 'hats/8'
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        name: 'Blue Snapback',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/X2VJP2W/blue-snapback.png',
        price: 16,
        linkUrl: 'hats/9'
      }
    ]
  },
  sneakers: {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Sneakers',
    routeName: 'sneakers',
    items: [
      {
        id: 10,
        name: 'Adidas NMD',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/0s3pdnc/adidas-nmd.png',
        price: 220,
        linkUrl: 'sneakers/10'

      },
      {
        id: 11,
        name: 'Adidas Yeezy',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/dJbG1cT/yeezy.png',
        price: 280,
        linkUrl: 'sneakers/11'
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        name: 'Black Converse',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/bPmVXyP/black-converse.png',
        price: 110,
        linkUrl: 'sneakers/12'
      },
      {
        id: 13,
        name: 'Nike White AirForce',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/1RcFPk0/white-nike-high-tops.png',
        price: 160,
        linkUrl: 'sneakers/13'
      },
      {
        id: 14,
        name: 'Nike Red High Tops',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/QcvzydB/nikes-red.png',
        price: 160,
        linkUrl: 'sneakers/14'
      },
      {
        id: 15,
        name: 'Nike Brown High Tops',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/fMTV342/nike-brown.png',
        price: 160,
        linkUrl: 'sneakers/15'
      },
      {
        id: 16,
        name: 'Air Jordan Limited',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/w4k6Ws9/nike-funky.png',
        price: 190,
        linkUrl: 'sneakers/16'
      },
      {
        id: 17,
        name: 'Timberlands',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/Mhh6wBg/timberlands.png',
        price: 200,
        linkUrl: 'sneakers/17'
      }
    ]
  },
  jackets: {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Jackets',
    routeName: 'jackets',
    items: [
      {
        id: 18,
        name: 'Black Jean Shearling',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/XzcwL5s/black-shearling.png',
        price: 125,
        linkUrl: 'jackets/18'
      },
      {
        id: 19,
        name: 'Blue Jean Jacket',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/mJS6vz0/blue-jean-jacket.png',
        price: 90,
        linkUrl: 'jackets/19'
      },
      {
        id: 20,
        name: 'Grey Jean Jacket',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/N71k1ML/grey-jean-jacket.png',
        price: 90,
        linkUrl: 'jackets/20'
      },
      {
        id: 21,
        name: 'Brown Shearling',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/s96FpdP/brown-shearling.png',
        price: 165,
        linkUrl: 'jackets/21'
      },
      {
        id: 22,
        name: 'Tan Trench',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/M6hHc3F/brown-trench.png',
        price: 185,
        linkUrl: 'jackets/22'
      }
    ]
  },
  womens: {
    id: 4,
    title: 'Womens',
    routeName: 'womens',
    items: [
      {
        id: 23,
        name: 'Blue Tanktop',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/7CQVJNm/blue-tank.png',
        price: 25,
        linkUrl: 'womens/23'
      },
      {
        id: 24,
        name: 'Floral Blouse',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/4W2DGKm/floral-blouse.png',
        price: 20,
        linkUrl: 'womens/24'
      },
      {
        id: 25,
        name: 'Floral Dress',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/KV18Ysr/floral-skirt.png',
        price: 80,
        linkUrl: 'womens/25'
      },
      {
        id: 26,
        name: 'Red Dots Dress',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/N3BN1bh/red-polka-dot-dress.png',
        price: 80,
        linkUrl: 'womens/26'
      },
      {
        id: 27,
        name: 'Striped Sweater',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/KmSkMbH/striped-sweater.png',
        price: 45,
        linkUrl: 'womens/27'
      },
      {
        id: 28,
        name: 'Yellow Track Suit',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/v1cvwNf/yellow-track-suit.png',
        price: 135,
        linkUrl: 'womens/28'
      },
      {
        id: 29,
        name: 'White Blouse',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/qBcrsJg/white-vest.png',
        price: 20,
        linkUrl: 'womens/29'
      }
    ]
  },
  mens: {
    id: 5,
    title: 'Mens',
    routeName: 'mens',
    items: [
      {
        id: 30,
        name: 'Camo Down Vest',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/xJS0T3Y/camo-vest.png',
        price: 325,
        linkUrl: 'mens/30'
      },
      {
        id: 31,
        name: 'Floral T-shirt',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/qMQ75QZ/floral-shirt.png',
        price: 20,
        linkUrl: 'mens/31'
      },
      {
        id: 32,
        name: 'Black & White Longsleeve',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/55z32tw/long-sleeve.png',
        price: 25,
        linkUrl: 'mens/32'
      },
      {
        id: 33,
        name: 'Pink T-shirt',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/RvwnBL8/pink-shirt.png',
        price: 25,
        linkUrl: 'mens/33'
      },
      {
        id: 34,
        name: 'Jean Long Sleeve',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/VpW4x5t/roll-up-jean-shirt.png',
        price: 40,
        linkUrl: 'mens/34'
      },
      {
        id: 35,
        name: 'Burgundy T-shirt',
        imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/mh3VM1f/polka-dot-shirt.png',
        price: 25,
        linkUrl: 'mens/35'
      }
    ]
  }
};

export default SHOP_DATA;
```

Currently, these are objects:

[image]

and I am trying to replace them with these:
[image]

**The reason why I used these objects instead of their category**, is because I want to make individual product pages, instead of a large category page that includes anything. However, I am not familiar with manipulating items in an array...

Here are the two files relating to structuring the shop data:
One is the individual item module: Collection component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import CollectionItem from '../../components/collection-item/collection-item.component';

import { selectCollection } from '../../redux/shop/shop.selectors';

import './collection.styles.scss';

const CollectionPage = ({ collection }) => {
  const { title, items } = collection;
  return (
    <div className='collection-page'>
      <h2 className='title'>{title}</h2>
      <div className='items'>
        {items.map(item => (
          <CollectionItem key={item.id} item={item} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  collection: selectCollection(ownProps.match.params.collectionId)(state)
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CollectionPage);
```

the other one Collection Overview component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';

import CollectionPreview from '../collection-preview/collection-preview.component';

import { selectCollectionsForPreview } from '../../redux/shop/shop.selectors';

import './collections-overview.styles.scss';

const CollectionsOverview = ({ collections }) => (
  <div className='collections-overview'>
    {collections.map(({ id, ...otherCollectionProps }) => (
      <CollectionPreview key={id} {...otherCollectionProps} />
    ))}
  </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  collections: selectCollectionsForPreview
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CollectionsOverview);
```

Thanks in advance.

The routing component update:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import CollectionsOverview from '../../components/collections-overview/collections-overview.component';
import CollectionPage from '../collection/collection.component';

const ShopPage = ({ match }) => (
  <div className='shop-page'>
    <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={CollectionsOverview} />
    <Route path={`${match.path}/:collectionId`} component={CollectionPage} />
  </div>
);

export default ShopPage;
```

Comment: Please include all code as properly formatted plain text code snippets, images are not searchable. You can use array::reduce to trivially reduce the array into an object.

Comment: I have added all the related files. Currently, the selector is using collection -> shop's items, which are hats, sneakers, jackets, womens, mens as url params, and it will generate pages like shop/hats, shop/sneakers etc. However, I want individual product page, not a category page. Hence, I think the problem is coming from the selector file. I should pass the right object... I want hats id as params, so that it will generate pages like shop/hats/1, and it will only show 1 picture per page, if that makes sense.... Thanks for all the help. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No worries. From what you describe this sounds more like a router/routing issue than a redux selector one. Do you have page containers on specific routes so you can pass the match params to a selector and pull the state you want?

Comment: Yes I have a component that does the job. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please paste your code in a text format instead of an image format. And you haven't shown what you are going to do in your question.

Note that `object` in JavaScript acts as a dictionary so that you should access it with `key` but you don't give what the key-value pair you want.

Comment: you are correct but this is not an answer but a comment, I'll change it to avoid down votes.

Answer (score 0):

It still isn't clear when or where you want to convert the nested `items` array into an object, so I'll just leave you the logic for converting it to an object with the `id` as key and the element as the value.

Given a specific collection, "hats", provided by `selectCollection` selector

```
const state = {shop: { collections: SHOP_DATA}};

const collection = selectCollection('hats')(state);
```

Yields

```
{
  id: 1,
  title: "Hats",
  routeName: "hats",
  items: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Brown Brim",
      imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/ZYW3VTp/brown-brim.png",
      price: 25,
      linkUrl: "hats/1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Blue Beanie",
      imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/ypkgK0X/blue-beanie.png",
      price: 18,
      linkUrl: "hats/2"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Brown Cowboy",
      imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/QdJwgmp/brown-cowboy.png",
      price: 35,
      linkUrl: "hats/3"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Grey Brim",
      imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/RjBLWxB/grey-brim.png",
      price: 25,
      linkUrl: "hats/4"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Green Beanie",
      imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/YTjW3vF/green-beanie.png",
      price: 18,
      linkUrl: "hats/5"
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: "Palm Tree Cap",
      imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/rKBDvJX/palm-tree-cap.png",
      price: 14,
      linkUrl: "hats/6"
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      name: "Red Beanie",
      imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/bLB646Z/red-beanie.png",
      price: 18,
      linkUrl: "hats/7"
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: "Wolf Cap",
      imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/1f2nWMM/wolf-cap.png",
      price: 14,
      linkUrl: "hats/8"
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      name: "Blue Snapback",
      imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/X2VJP2W/blue-snapback.png",
      price: 16,
      linkUrl: "hats/9"
    }
  ]
}
```

Let's call this object `collection`. In order to convert the `items` array to an object you can reduce that array into an object.

```
collections.items.reduce(
  (items, item) => ({
    ...items,
    [item.id]: item
  }),
  {}
);
```

Yielding object

```
{
  '1': {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Brown Brim',
    imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/ZYW3VTp/brown-brim.png',
    price: 25,
    linkUrl: 'hats/1',
  },
  '2': {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Blue Beanie',
    imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/ypkgK0X/blue-beanie.png',
    price: 18,
    linkUrl: 'hats/2',
  },
  '3': {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Brown Cowboy',
    imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/QdJwgmp/brown-cowboy.png',
    price: 35,
    linkUrl: 'hats/3',
  },
  '4': {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Grey Brim',
    imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/RjBLWxB/grey-brim.png',
    price: 25,
    linkUrl: 'hats/4',
  },
  '5': {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Green Beanie',
    imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/YTjW3vF/green-beanie.png',
    price: 18,
    linkUrl: 'hats/5',
  },
  '6': {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Palm Tree Cap',
    imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/rKBDvJX/palm-tree-cap.png',
    price: 14,
    linkUrl: 'hats/6',
  },
  '7': {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Red Beanie',
    imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/bLB646Z/red-beanie.png',
    price: 18,
    linkUrl: 'hats/7',
  },
  '8': {
    id: 8,
    name: 'Wolf Cap',
    imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/1f2nWMM/wolf-cap.png',
    price: 14,
    linkUrl: 'hats/8',
  },
  '9': {
    id: 9,
    name: 'Blue Snapback',
    imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/X2VJP2W/blue-snapback.png',
    price: 16,
    linkUrl: 'hats/9',
  },
}
```